# Error with super structure in inheritance attempt (typescript classes)

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, typescript-generics

```
class Character {
    public readonly name: string;
    public readonly level: number;

    constructor(name: string, level: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }

    walk() {
        return `${this.name} walking!`
    }

    showMyLevel() {
        return `${this.name} has the level ${this.level}`
    }
}

class Wizzard extends Character {
    private readonly cajado: string;

    constructor(cajado: string) {
        super(name, level);
        this.cajado = cajado;
    }

    fireBall() {
        return `${this.name} fire ball!`
    }

}

const wizzard1 = new Wizzard('Ray', 8);

console.log(wizzard1.fireBall());
```

I would like my Wizard class to inherit my Character class and implement a constructor with one more item. However in super() I am getting errors

```
const name: void
@deprecated

'name' is deprecated.ts(6385)
lib.dom.d.ts(17877, 5): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

```
Cannot find name 'level'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.level'?ts(2663)
```

I thought this could be happening because the variables are private in readonly, but changing it to public returns the same problem. Would you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parameters to the `Wizzard` class that match the `Character` class.

```
class Wizzard extends Character {
    private readonly cajado: string;

    constructor(name: string, level: number, cajado: string) {
        super(name, level);
        this.cajado = cajado;
    }

    fireBall() {
        return `${this.name} fire ball!`
    }

}
```

Also note that `Wizard` is the correct spelling, not `Wizzard`.